# Django - After removing a table from models.py and migrations I get "relation "<table name> does not exist"

Tags: python, django

So I realized I could just remove a table and add it as a ManyToMany relation to another model and I removed the creation of the table from the migration files in the folder. But for some reason I'm getting the error below when I call `python manage.py migrate`

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "<table name>" does not exist
```

How do you properly remove tables and or add attributes to models in models.py without causing errors when you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Don't mess with migration files unless you know what you are doing. You should have simply deleted the model class from your `models.py` and let migrations deal with the database.

Answer (score -1):

In your project

1. delete the `migrations` folder
2. Create a new migrations folder and create an empty `__init__.py` file inside it.
3. run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

By doing this Django will create fresh migrations for your project.

Comment: are there any downsides of deleting your migrations? Is it bad practice?

Comment: Do not delete your migrations. Because deleting your migrations doesn't delete the tables created by them in your database. If you delete them you will get an error saying `table <table_name> already exist`. Instead write back the deleted `create_model` query in your migration file using this doc, `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/writing-migrations/`. Once done, remove the table code in `models.py` and run `python manage.py makemigrations and then `python manage.py migrate`. 
That will solve your issue to get rid of the table.